# Converting between a Mac file path to a Windows file path

Tags: macos, windows, path, file-conversion

I am working in an office that is dominated by PCs, but we are moving select designers to a Mac platform (testing). The biggest issue I have come across is sharing file paths to shared drives, and the formatting differences. Please tell me there is a simple answer.

I am looking for a way for our designers to write an email and link to a file on the drive, but convert the file path to windows formatting. And visa versa (getting an email with a windows file path, and converting it to a mac file path).

File path examples:
Mac formatting: /Volumes/Share/Main Folder/Folder1/Folder2/FinalFolder
Windows formatting: S:\Main Folder\Folder1\Folder2\FinalFolder

We have multiple shared drives, so it could be multiple letters, not just "S".

Comment: You want this conversion done where? In the link embedded in the email depending on what platform you happen to be reading the email from? That might be a question for serverfault.com as it's going to be about your email client-server setup and less about your Mac setup.

Comment: It's mainly a communication issue between coworkers. I'm only going to equip the mac users with the ability to convert back and forth as needed. There are only going to be a few of them, so when they email out - they will email out using a windows link. But if they receive a link, they'll need to convert to a mac formatted link.

Answer (score 1):

Stay with the Windows path style and install [WinShortcutter 3.5 (Freeware)](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/WinShortcutter/index.html) on the Mac side. Since you are using mapped drives on the Windows PCs: e.g. `S:\Main Folder\Folder1...` you have to configure the proper mappings e.g `\\Share\pictures\ -> S:\` in the app on every Mac though.

Comment: We're a really secure network here, so downloading third party applications is not going to be an easy task to pass through.